# What is the lowest dimension $d$ for which the simple random walk on $\mathbb Z^d$ is transient?

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

By "transient" I think they mean that the probability of returning to the initial point is $<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest such $d$ is $3$. Here is a [reference.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html)